# Php exercise with strings

Tags: php, string

I should write a php code with two strings and as a result a third string composed by alternately the even letters of the first two strings. 
For example: 'pippo', 'lucia' -> 'iupi'.
Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: `Could you help me?` Of course. But, show us your effort.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What if the strings are not equal lenght? What if string 1 is 15 characters long and the other only 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firstString = 'pippo';
$secondString = 'lucia';

$result = '';

for ($i = 1; $i < max(strlen($firstString), strlen($secondString)); $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    if (isset($firstString[$i])) {
        $result .= $firstString[$i];
    }
    if (isset($secondString[$i])) {
        $result .= $secondString[$i];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

I really encourage you to do such simple things by yourself otherwise learning to code will be a lot harder for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a beginner so I'm trying to figure out how things work